# trim last column in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv which looks like

[image]

I am able to convert it into a dataframe but the last column "Boh" has lot of spaces.
So when I print columns, it is showing as

```
 ['Product ID','Location','Boh         ']
```

How trim last column in my df ? So that the columns will be

```
    ['Product ID','Location','Boh']
```

Comment: Why does it have those spaces? How did you load it in? `df = pd.read_csv(..., sep=';')`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove whitespaces with all columns names:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

But if need remove only by last value:

```
df = df.rename(columns = dict(zip(df.columns[-1], df.columns[-1].strip())))
```

Comment: If the question means what you think it does then this is a duplicate

Comment: hmmm, we can see..